# IBM FileNet fix pack 5.2.1.7 installed twice

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine, filenet-cpe

Once of our resources did a mistake. We have 5.2.1.7 running in prod. By accidentally, same fix pack was installed on prod once again. While installing development server name was provided for com comparability layer and wcmapi config link.

Post installation, we have not restarted the servers (windows). How much trouble are we in now? What are the steps that we need to take care?

Hope you have some answers to this.

Comment: whoever voted for closing this question, should at least give some reason so that, it helps me in posting the future question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what we tried

1. Took a backup of the server
2. Ran the fix pack installation again on the prod server
3. This time ensured that correct server details were provided for com
   compatibility and wcmapiconfig.props
4. Bounced the server and everything is working as expected.